Origin of module theory
A mathematician named Emmy Noether developed module theory, which is a theory that extends from ring theory. Module theory is widely used in mathematics, but it has become an essential theory in mathematical research to the point that it is also used in physics. That's why I became interested in module theory. What was the motivation or historical background that led Emmy Noether to create module theory? And additionally, what is the etymology of the word module in module theory, and why was it named that way?

Emmy Noether introduced the modern abstract concept, but the theory of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, along with the term, is due to Dedekind in 1871, see Gray, A History of Abstract Algebra, 17.4 and MathOverflow thread. Noether's theory was an abstract generalization of Dedekind's, part of her general program of detaching algebra from concrete realizations like numbers and polynomials.
Dedekind's motivation was his studies of factorization of algebraic integers along the lines introduced earlier by Kummer to prove  Fermat’s Last Theorem in special cases. Ideals first came up in the same work. The word "module" was Dedekind's self-translation of German Modul into French in his Sur la Théorie des Nombres entiers algébriques (1877). E.T. Bell then transplanted it into English in Successive Generalizations in the Theory of Numbers (1927). According to Stillwell, who translated Dedekind's Theory of Algebraic Integers into English, "Dedekind presumably chose the name 'module' because a module $M$ is something for which 'congruence modulo $M$' is meaningful."
From Gray:

"Dedekind turned to build up his general theory.
He called a module a system (i.e., in later language a set) a of numbers closed under
addition and subtraction. (It is indeed a $\mathbb{Z}$ module in modern terminology.) He said
that if the difference of two numbers belonged to $\mathbf{a}$ then they were congruent modulo
$\mathbf{a}$, written $ω ≡ ω'\pmod{\mathbf{a}}$. 
He then said that if all the members of a module $\mathbf{a}$ are members of a module
$\mathbf{b}$ then a is a multiple of $\mathbf{b}$ and that $\mathbf{b}$ divides $\mathbf{a}$. To remember this, note that $6$ is
a multiple of $3$ and the set of multiples of $6$ is a subset of the multiples of $3$. The
set of elements common to $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ he called the least common multiple of the two modules. He called the set of all sums of the form $α+β$, where $α$ is in $\mathbf{a}$ and $β$ is in $\mathbf{b}$, the greatest common divisor of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. He then introduced the concept of an ideal in a number field... The algebra of modules extends to ideals."


This is perhaps more of a long comment than an answer, and it is speculative.
The word "modulus" (without justification for the coinage) was introduced by Gauss in 1801 in his Disquisitiones Arithmeticae, essentially defined by the familiar congruence relationship $b \equiv c \mod a$, which is still standard notation today. It is also understood to be the etymological stem of "module" as used today since Dedekind and E. Noether.
To the best of my knowledge Gauss never explained the reason for picking the term, but if I may provide some sourced speculation. Gauss actually wrote a letter in 1799 to the editor of a Volume of collected results including a corrected computation including the units "Modulen" (see Gauss, Werke Band 8, p. 136). The volume he refers to is

Allgemeine Geographische Ephemeriden. Herausgegeben von F. von Zach. Vierter Band. 4. Stück. October 1799. S. 378. Weimar, 1799. pp. xxxiv-xxxv.

where one finds the following definition of Module (as German word):

Hence a "module" is a normed measuring rod with integer subdivisions. Could it be that Gauss took this notion as model for his nomenclature? Given that a modulus defines the number of integers in its equivalence class? Unfortunately I am not aware of a source that could move this from speculation to plausibility or certainty.

"Module" is here meant as a unit of measure (like the "Modulor", invented by Le Corbusier in architecture). It is interesting that Gauss mentions in fact the newly "invented" meter (under the name "toise" the former unit of length in France) under its long-lasting definition : $1/40000000$th of the length of the equator
